# Redirect to URL then update menu ( Ajax) in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem when the user clicks on the link, it must redirect to the page then update the left-menu.

But when i put the url link in href. it update the menu then rediect to the page. Then, the menu disappear.

The code in the Layout Page

```
<a class="Tab" href="~/Default1" data-tabid='1'> Link1 </a>
<a class="Tab" href="~/Default2" data-tabid='2'> Link2 </a>
<a class="Tab" href="~/Default3" data-tabid='3'> Link3 </a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.Tab').click(function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault(); alert($(this).data('taskid'));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "MenuItem/Menu",
                data: { MenuId: $(this).data('tabid') },
                dataType: "html",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#menuContent").html(data);
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });

        });


    </script>
```

**Any help is highly appreciated.**

Comment: It is not clear from your code and question what you are trying to do.

Comment: when the user clicks on the link, I want to redirect him to a new page then display a menu. The code here will display the menu then redirect to the page, so the menu in the new page will be empty.

Comment: Have your tried adding the menu in the Master page?

Comment: in My code the menu has a section in the layout page & it must communicate with menu class. I am using razor view engine.